# Nested UI in list items not horizontally aligning correctly

Tags: windows, xaml, uwp, windows-10, uwp-xaml

I'm trying to horizontally align a nested UI (button) inside a list view item to the right, but for some reason, this isn't working.

*Expected result*

[image]

*Current result*

[image]

*XAML*

```
<controls:MasterDetailsView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,8">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding From}" 
                       Style="{ThemeResource SubtitleTextBlockStyle}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Body}" 
                       Style="{ThemeResource BodyTextBlockStyle}" 
                       Opacity=".6" 
                       MaxLines="1"/>
            </StackPanel>

            <Button Grid.Column="1" 
                    Background="Transparent" 
                    Content="&#xE712;" 
                    FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    Margin="10" 
                    Padding="10" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</controls:MasterDetailsView.ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set the **HorizontalContentAlignment** of ListViewItem to **Stretch** in ItemContainerStyle. It will stretch the child element to fill the allocated space of the MasterDetailsView.

.xaml:

```
<controls:MasterDetailsView ItemsSource="{x:Bind Items,Mode=OneWay}" CompactModeThresholdWidth="720">
    <controls:MasterDetailsView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        </Style>
    </controls:MasterDetailsView.ItemContainerStyle>

    <controls:MasterDetailsView.ItemTemplate>
        ......
    </controls:MasterDetailsView.ItemTemplate>

</controls:MasterDetailsView>
```